# Is there a POSIX header that defines maximum prefix lengths for IPv4/6?

Tags: c, ip

I want something like `INET[6]_ADDRSTRLEN` but containing the maximum value of the prefix length, i.e. 32 for v4 and 128 for v6.

Obviously I can `#define` my own versions, but wondered if I was just ignorant of the correct header. I've looked in `<arpa/inet.h>` and similar but not found anything.

Comment: Perhaps `sizeof(in_addr_t)` and `sizeof(s6_addr) * 8` ?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: For the sake of symmetry I'd propose: `8 * sizeof (struct in_addr)` and `8 * sizeof (struct in6_addr))`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: I'm not sure that's clearer for the case that I'm using it for. I'm basically setting a default value of 32 or 128, depending on the address family. I think something like `#define INET_MAX_PREFIX_LEN 32` and `#define INET6_MAX_PREFIX_LEN 128` would be clearest, if they don't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

`<netinet/in.h>` could be what you are searching

[netinet/in.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/netinet/in.h.html)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, but would have better suited as comment.

Comment: I agree but I can't comment for now, should I delete ?

Comment: Comment now, then delete. ;-)

Comment: I need 50rep to comment :'(